# Paginate with cache returns collection Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

When I use cache with paginate, paginate return collection. Why? MY code:

```
    $shops = Cache::rememberForever('shops', function() {
        return Shop::active()->paginate(30);
    });
```

When I do:

```
    dd($shops);
```

I get collection, but not paginator object. Why?

Comment: Did you solve your issue?

Comment: @DavideCasiraghi nope

Answer (score 0):

I guess in this post they are considering a similar scenarios:

- [Laravel cache::remember is returing object as an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44028121/laravel-cacheremember-is-returing-object-as-an-array)
- [Paginate Eloquent collection](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/paginate-eloquent-collection)

**You can create a pagination instance manually.**

```
$page = Input::get('page', 1); // Get the ?page=1 from the url
$perPage = 15; // Number of items per page
$offset = ($page * $perPage) - $perPage;

return new LengthAwarePaginator(
    array_slice($shops->toArray(), $offset, $perPage, true), // Only grab the items we need
    count($shops), // Total items
    $perPage, // Items per page
    $page, // Current page
    ['path' => $request->url(), 'query' => $request->query()] // We need this so we can keep all old query parameters from the url
);
```

Here you can find the official [Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/pagination#manually-creating-a-paginator) about **Manually Creating A Paginator**